# Python installation: What should you do after using python3 setup.py install

Tags: python

I am trying to build a python library for embedded device without wifi access and without pip installation usage

First I start off with downloading the package from PyPi website. After opening the gz file, I found and read the setup.py and then download its dependencies accordingly.

For my environment, I start to trial out the installation on a VM as trial(yah it is far from being the perfect environment) and try to setup the packages in a virtual environment.

After running `python3 setup.py install` for all of them, I found that almost all the installation is installed onto  `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` instead of in the virtual environment `/helper/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. Subsequently I copied the content in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` to the '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` and try to run python from the activated environment.

However the program give an error "zipp" module not found. Thinking that I have missed out a module, I proceed to downnload the package and tried to setup manually. However there is no setup.py in the folder. There seem to be no installation available

So my question is this:

1. How do i install to a virtual environment folder? Do I copied the contents `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` to `/helper/lib/python3.8/site-packages` like what I did? Or is there other files I will have to copy over?
2. How do I install packages like `zipp` which do not have any setup.py and there seem to be no installation instruction whatsoever. Do I copy `zipp.egg-info` over to the site folder

Thanks